# Login to javascript webpage with Excel vba - Modification

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I was trying to use solution from this post [Login to javascript webpage with Excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237513/login-to-javascript-webpage-with-excel-vba)

for my purposes but I failed to (I'm not programmer just finance guy). Could you please help me how to "click" button on this [page](https://ppuslugi.mf.gov.pl/?link=VAT&)

```
Login procedure
ie.document.getElementById("b-7").Value = "7740001454"
ie.document.forms("DocumentForm").Submit
```

Submit is causing error and not working :/

Comment: Please provide the actual code that you are using. and What is the error that you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try the below Code, as it is working for me

```
Sub Temp()
  With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  .Navigate "https://ppuslugi.mf.gov.pl/?link=VAT&;"
  .Visible = True
  Do Until .ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
  Loop
  DoEvents
  With .document
     .getElementById("b-7").Value = "7740001454"
     .getElementById("b-8").Click
  End With
 End With
End Sub
```